# Informatica Mapping Design

Tags: mapping, etl

I need to do two things: 
In one of the column in my Target Table in mapping designer, I need to pull the date. I have two different source I in Teradata For ex. Table A and Table B. I need to pull the date in the date column in my Target Table (which is also in Teradata as well)  from Table B. if the date column is null in Table B, in that case, pull from Table A. If it is null in both tables, leave the consent_date col in Target Table col null as well.

Table A

ID - ----------------1060666

cosent_date --- 11/22/2013 18:00:04.970

Table B

ID - ----------------1060666

cosent_date --- 11/22/2013 6:00:05 PM

With my current design, I have consent_date from Table A mapped to Target Table Consent_Date column but I get no data in the Target at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your data type and If you cant find anymistake in it do share your datatype used in teradata as well in your informatica mappings